# cpp - alias for member functions` return types

Tags: c++, alias, return-type, type-alias

I've been watching [this CppCon talk](https://youtu.be/O65lEiYkkbc?t=2839) where the speaker was talking about writing classes resistant to future changes. He provided the following code as an example (that I show here abridged):

```
template< typename Type, size_t Cap >
class FixedVector final
{
    using iterator = Type*;
    
    iterator begin();
}
```

My question is, basically the following - *Does he use type aliasing here only because the type itself is already provided by the user of the class (and is a priory know to them)?* I mean, if that was not the case, then there is not way the user can use the aliased return type, right?

Comment: The user of the class has to provide `Type`, so the user of the class knows what `Type` is.  The `Type*` is being used as an *iterator*, so needs to comply with *iterator* behavior/properties.  (Which, in this case, is easy to do.  Since it is a `FixedVector`.)

Comment: "_I mean, if that was not the case, then there is not way the user can use the aliased return type, right?_": The users of the class shouldn't need to care what specific type `iterator` is nor are they allowed to depend on it. They should only use the type according to the random-access/contiguous iterator requirements. So it is better to not claim in the public interface that you return `Type*` specifically as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point they are trying to make is if they had

```
template< typename Type, size_t Cap >
class FixedVector final
{
    Type* begin();
}
```

and later they decide that instead of a `Type*`, they want to use a `my_custom_iterator<Type>`, then they need to make that change to all places that use `Type*`.  By using

```
class FixedVector final
{
    using iterator = Type*;
    
    iterator begin();
}
```

if you want to make that same change it is as simple as changing

```
using iterator = Type*;
```

to be

```
using iterator = my_custom_iterator<Type>;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Just to clarify, if you won't mind - so this is all about the internals of the class and ease of its maintenance?

Comment: @AntonTretyakov Yes.  This is about making future changes to the code easier, i.e. increasing its maintainability.